# Neo4j import-tool succeeds but results are not showing up

Tags: neo4j

I recently started using the import tool for faster load times, and so far the results were promising, except that they are not reflected in my database afterwards through cypher.

My process:

```
$ /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j stop
$ rm -rf /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data/
$ mkdir /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data
$ /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j-import --nodes:record /path/to/records.csv --into /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data
```

tmp.csv:

```
meta:ID,time:long,lat:float,lon:float
KAQP_20140420v20001_0000,1397970000,26.9387950897,-91.2847290039
KAQP_20140420v20001_0001,1397970060,26.9387989044,-91.2847595215
.... (1440 lines of the same record format) ...
```

Results of the call to neo4j-import tool:

```
Neo4j version: 3.0.3
Importing the contents of these files into neo4j-community-3.0.3/data:
Nodes:
  :record
  /neo4j/tmp.csv

Available memory:
  Free machine memory: 23.65 GB
  Max heap memory : 6.87 GB

Nodes

Done in 384ms
Prepare node index
[*:7.63 MB------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]    0
Done in 34ms
Calculate dense nodes

Done in 10ms
Node --> Relationship Sparse

Done in 10ms
Relationship --> Relationship Sparse

Done in 10ms
Node counts

Done in 51ms
Relationship counts

Done in 10ms

IMPORT DONE in 2s 360ms. Imported:
  1440 nodes
  0 relationships
  5760 properties
```

Excellent, everything looks great so far. So now I start up neo4j:

```
$ /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j start
```

Then I attempt to get the count of records:

```
$ /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j-shell -c 'MATCH (r:record) RETURN count(r) as count;'

+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
1 row
42 ms
```

That was strange, so I thought maybe the label wasn't registered or something? So instead I tried this:

```
$ /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j-shell -c 'MATCH (r) RETURN count(r) as count;'


+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
1 row
28 ms
```

This is really weird. My next thought was maybe the directory is being weird? So I tested the size of `/path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data`:

Before:

```
$ du -sh /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data
4K
```

After:

```
$ du -sh /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data
53M
```

Its definitely in there! I have no clue if I just missed a crucial step. Anyw idea whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the dir `$NEO4J_HOME/data/databases/graph.db` when you call `neo4j-import`:

```
/path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/neo4j-import --nodes:record /path/to/records.csv --into /path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data/databases/graph.db
```

or create the import somewhere else and replace the contents of `$NEO4J_HOME/data/databases/graph.db` with the datastore created by `neo4j-import`

Comment: Wow! Nice and simple. I must of overlooked that path tail in the docs. Thanks for quick response again!

Comment: I don't understand this answer...the OP wanted the database to be located here `/path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data`, so why do they have to locate the database here: `/path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data/databases/graph.db`? What if there already is a database at `/databases/graph.db`? I must be totally mistaken, but it appears that this means you can only have one database at a time, if all dbs must be located at the same location.

Comment: ...and/or are you saying that the import tool can only import into one location...and that's `graph.db`?

Comment: Monica, I believe William realized that I was using the default databse directory when starting up Neo4J. This is `/path/to/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data/databases/graph.db`. So of course, I probably could have stuck with only the `/../data` directory and changed the directory path from within the Neo4j settings (i think this may be in the `neo4j.properties` file). But instead of searching for this configuration I ended up just reloading my csv file into the suggested path since it was a simple change.